# What is the difference between using a method or a function outside React component

Tags: reactjs, methods

Recently i found a React component that uses a function outside the component in a `onClick` attribute. The reasoning behind that is that, and i quote: "it is better to use a function outsite the React component when there is not need to use `this` context". I personally don't find that answer very satisfying.

You can find a codesanbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/9221lpzvy)

There's any real difference? maybe in performance?

Thanks!

Comment: The only reason why I'm putting everything I can outside of react component are tests. It is much easier to test it as a standalone function, than render it and then call my function on instance. I think there could be performance reasons also, as standalone function is taken once on the very beginning when the file is interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

You must effectively write function outside of component if you don't need "this" context. The benefits is that the outside function is instantiated only one time and shared by all the component instances.